# Getting recent changes to Active Directory distribution lists, using powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, active-directory

I'm looking to automate the synchronization of Active Directory and an external application. Part of this includes synchronizing changes to Active Directory distribution groups.

Is there a way to find what members have been added/removed from a distribution group in AD since a certain date (using PowerShell)? I would prefer not to have to copy over the entire list each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know of any Powershell command that will do this for you.
But the Repadmin tool has some meta data that could help you.

Boe Prox has created this function to do what you are asking through the repadmin tool and shared it on the [Technet Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Find-the-time-a-user-was-a0bfc0cf)

```
Function Get-ADGroupMemberDate {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
            Provides the date that a member was added to a specified Active Directory group.

        .DESCRIPTION
            Provides the date that a member was added to a specified Active Directory group.

        .PARAMETER Group
            The group that will be inspected for members and date added. If a distinguished name (dn) is not used,
            an attempt to get the dn before making the query.

        .PARAMETER DomainController
            Name of the domain controller to query. Optional parameter.

        .NOTES
            Name: Get-ADGroupMemberDate
            Author: Boe Prox
            DateCreated: 17 May 2013
            Version 1.0

            The State property will be one of the following:

            PRESENT: User currently exists in group and the replicated using Linked Value Replication (LVR).
            ABSENT: User has been removed from group and has not been garbage collected based on Tombstone Lifetime (TSL).
            LEGACY: User currently exists as a member of the group but has no replication data via LVR.

        .EXAMPLE
            Get-ADGroupMemberDate -Group "Domain Admins" -DomainController DC3

            ModifiedCount    : 2
            DomainController : DC3
            LastModified     : 5/4/2013 6:48:06 PM
            Username         : joesmith
            State            : ABSENT
            Group            : CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=Domain,DC=Com

            ModifiedCount    : 1
            DomainController : DC3
            LastModified     : 1/6/2010 7:36:08 AM
            Username         : adminuser
            State            : PRESENT
            Group            : CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=Domain,DC=Com
            ...

            Description
            -----------
            This lists out all of the members of Domain Admins using DC3 as the Domain Controller.

        .EXAMPLE
            Get-ADGroup -Identity "TestGroup" | Get-ADGroupMemberDate

            ModifiedCount    : 2
            DomainController : DC1
            LastModified     : 5/4/2013 6:48:06 PM
            Username         : joesmith
            State            : ABSENT
            Group            : CN=TestGroup,OU=Groups,DC=Domain,DC=Com

            ModifiedCount    : 1
            DomainController : DC1
            LastModified     : 1/6/2010 7:36:08 AM
            Username         : bobsmith
            State            : PRESENT
            Group            : CN=TestGroup,OU=Groups,DC=Domain,DC=Com
            ...

            Description
            -----------
            This lists out all of the members of TestGroup from the output of Get-ADGroup and auto-selecting DC1 as the Domain Controller.

    #>
    [OutputType('ActiveDirectory.Group.Info')]
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True,Mandatory=$True)]
        [Alias('DistinguishedName')]
        [string]$Group,
        [parameter()]
        [string]$DomainController = ($env:LOGONSERVER -replace "\\\\")
    )
    Begin {
        #RegEx pattern for output
        [regex]$pattern = '^(?<State>\w+)\s+member(?:\s(?<DateTime>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(?:.*\\)?(?<DC>\w+|(?:(?:\w{8}-(?:\w{4}-){3}\w{12})))\s+(?:\d+)\s+(?:\d+)\s+(?<Modified>\d+))?'
    }
    Process {
        If ($Group -notmatch "^CN=.*") {
            Write-Verbose "Attempting to get distinguished name of $Group"

            Try {
                $distinguishedName = ([adsisearcher]"name=$group").Findone().Properties['distinguishedname'][0]
                If (-Not $distinguishedName) {Throw "Fail!"}
            } Catch {
                Write-Warning "Unable to locate $group"
                Break                
            }

        } Else {$distinguishedName = $Group}

        Write-Verbose "Distinguished Name is $distinguishedName"
        $data = (repadmin /showobjmeta $DomainController $distinguishedName | Select-String "^\w+\s+member" -Context 2)

        ForEach ($rep in $data) {
           If ($rep.line -match $pattern) {
               $object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    Username = [regex]::Matches($rep.context.postcontext,"CN=(?<Username>.*?),.*") | ForEach {$_.Groups['Username'].Value}
                    LastModified = If ($matches.DateTime) {[datetime]$matches.DateTime} Else {$Null}
                    DomainController = $matches.dc
                    Group = $distinguishedName
                    State = $matches.state
                    ModifiedCount = $matches.modified
                }

                $object.pstypenames.insert(0,'ActiveDirectory.Group.Info')
                $object
            }
        }
    }
}
```